# LibGDX: newServerSocket causes null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, libgdx, server

I am trying to start a LibGDX server. I have copied the code from this site: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/net/PingPongSocketExample.java but I am getting a null pointer exception from the line Server server = Gdx.net.newServerSocket... What is going on?

Comment: Can you post the exact exception and LibGDX version? `AndroidNet` never returns null from the method that you posted. Are you sure that you're invoking it _after_ the application is already started?

Comment: Ah, there is the problem, I am not starting an application at all... :P Makes sense.

Comment: `Gdx.net` is null unless you start an application - if you just want to use the networking functionalities, try creating `Net` implementation object manually, for example: `new LwjglNet().newServerSocket(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibGDX static utility variables start as `null`. They are not assigned immediately (and are not final) to support different implementations on each platform. For example, `Net` implementation that you reference with `Gdx.net` is `null` unless you start an application that actually assigns this value.

If you want the server to be a part of your regular client application, try starting the application first and *then* creating the server socket. If you want a separate server application, you can use the [`headless`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends/gdx-backend-headless) backend. You can also create `Net` instance manually, for example: `new HeadlessNet().newServerSocket(...)` or `new AndroidNet().newServerSocket(...)`.

`Net` implementations are basically simple stateless factories on most platforms, so it's OK to have a few instances of them; even if you construct `Net` instance manually and *then* create an application, it should cause no problems.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! Right now I am getting another problem, though. In my server class, I am unable to import LwjglNet. When trying to run, Gradle says that the package com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl does not exist. However, if I try to import it in a different class, it works fine. I suspect there is a problem with the build configuration..?

Comment: You're probably trying to import this class in `core` project. Core has only, well, core dependencies: the abstractions used by other platforms. `LwjglNet` is a class specific to desktop platform. Core project simply does not have this dependency - I'd suggest making a separate project with [`gdx-backend-headless`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-backend-headless) if you want a server application.

Comment: There are several ways to solve NPE issue, it would be helpful to know what you're trying to achieve. If creating a server socket is a part of pretty much every client application, you can just wait until application is fully created and use `Gdx.net` for cross-platform API. If you want a separate "global" server, try headless backend.